# PHP delete button always starts deleting the last row

Tags: php, mysql

[image: booklist.php on webbrowser]enter image description here

[image: Database Table Contents]

[image: Database Table Structure]

Okay, so this may be just simple for you guys since you have experience but I can't get to figure out why is it that everytime I hit "Delete" button on the first row of my table, it deletes the last row instead of the row on which I hit "Delete." Only happens on the first row. Second row would delete just perfectly on the database.

Is there anything wrong with my code or is there a problem with my table structure? I've provided my code for two separate php files namely booklist.php and edit.php I would appreciate your help as I am really new with PHP. Not yet familiar with all the rules and what not. Thanks.

```
//booklist.php below
echo "<form method='POST' action='edit.php'>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    $bookID_Var = $row['No'];
    $titleVar = $row['Title'];
    $authorVar = $row['Author'];  //authorVar is a variable container for the value of Author row in librarydatabase
    $ISBN = $row['ISBN'];

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$bookID_Var. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $titleVar. "</td>";   // there's no need to quote variables. In this line, we used variables $authorVar and $titleVar
        echo "<td>" . $authorVar. "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $ISBN . "</td>";
        echo "<td> <input type='submit' value='Edit'> </td>"; // Edit button
        echo "<td> <input type='submit'  name='delete' value='Delete'> </td>"; // Delete button

        echo "</tr>"; 
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='bookID' value='  " .$bookID_Var. "  '>";

    } // end of while loop

    echo "</form>";



//edit.php below

<?php
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    echo "entered delete if block <br />";
    echo "Value: " . $_REQUEST['bookID'];

    $bookID = $_REQUEST['bookID'];
    $sql = " DELETE FROM booklist WHERE No='$bookID'  ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if ($result) {
        echo "Successfully deleted" . "Book ID: " . $bookID;
    }
} // end of main if
?>
```

Comment: It's related to phpmyadmin tool not php language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach :-

use `hyperlink` not `input`

```
echo "<a href='edit.php?act=delete&id=<?php echo $bookID; ?> '>Delete</a>";
```

or php code :-

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act']=='delete'){
$bookID=$_GET['act'];
 $sql = " DELETE FROM booklist WHERE No='$bookID'  ";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. using hyperlink and redirecting it to a separate delete.php file solved my problem. Is it recommended to use hyperlinks when passing values instead of input / button? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First. Follow conventions. Name your `primary keys` as id. Second - try to echo your `query`. Are you sure, if your `$_REQUEST['bookID'] == 14?` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 $sql = " DELETE FROM booklist WHERE No='$bookID'  ";
```

to

```
echo  $sql = " DELETE FROM booklist WHERE No=".$bookID;exit;
```

and test which id is passed i am sure there is issue of passing an id.

Comment: Thanks, echoing helped me in debugging. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use link action rather than submit action to delete based on rows:

E.g:

Change:

```
<input type='submit'  name='delete' value='Delete'>
```

to

```
<a href="edit.php?bookID=<?php echo $row['No'] ?>">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Imran. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use one form for the entire data set, your hidden field will have the same name in every row. It seems the last one overrides all the previous ones.

There are better ways of passing down the id of each row, one simple method would be to separate out your deletion logic into `delete.php`, then you could put the Delete button as a link, and not a form, and have each row link to `delete.php?bookid=<id>`.

Comment: This definitely helped. I put it on a separate deleted.php file. It made things easier for me to debug. Thank you.